# Two's complement in verilog

Tags: verilog

I've been trying to build a module which returns the two's complement representation of the (3-bit) input (first bit being the sign). I think that the following code is correct conceptually, but I am probably missing something about it's structure: when I try to compile, I get the following errors:

```
(vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "f_o".
(vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "f_o".
(vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "f_o".
```

Searching for that error showed it is usually seen when using a variable as input and output at the same time, but that's not my case. Could you point where the error is?

```
module ca2 (a_i,f_o);
  input  [2:0] a_i;
  output [2:0] f_o;

  always @(a_i[2:0] or f_o[2:0])
  begin
    if (a_i[2] == 1)
    begin
      f_o[2]   = a_i[2];
      f_o[1:0] = (~a_i[1:0] + 'b1);
    end
    else
    begin
      f_o = a_i;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Verilog, undeclared identifiers are considered implicit wire declarations in most circumstances. Since f_o has not been declared the compiler considers it a wire, not a variable. This causes the compiler to complain about all the assignments.

```
// What was typed
module ca2 (a_i,f_o);
  input  [2:0] a_i;
  output [2:0] f_o;

// What the compiler implicitly declares
  wire   [2:0] a_i;
  wire   [2:0] f_o;
```

To fix it you can declare the variable or declare both the port and the variable.

```
module ca2 (a_i,f_o);
  input  [2:0] a_i;
  output [2:0] f_o; 
  reg [2:0] f_o;

module ca2 (a_i,f_o);
  input      [2:0] a_i;
  output reg [2:0] f_o;
```

Answer (score 2):

`f_o` needs to be declared as a reg. `output reg [2:0] f_o`.

Also I am not sure what you are calculating, that is not a standard twos complement.

```
module ca2 (
  input      [2:0] a_i,
  output     [2:0] twos_comp,
  output     [2:0] also_twos_comp
);

  assign      twos_comp = ~a_i + 1'b1;
  assign also_twos_comp = -a_i ;
endmodule
```

You may be dealing with an encoded input, but twos_complement is to negate the number I would expect the sign bit (MSB) to change. Although we refer to it as a sign bit it also contains information about the value and therefore can not just be stripped off and leave the number unchanged.

Comment: Thank you too, the solution to the problem is the same as Adam12. About your other comment, what basically I am doing is leave the number unchanged if the input is positive, and if it is indeed negative, change to ca2 representation (ie: if input is 101 it means -3, and the ca2 is 011). I don't know if I'm making much sense with the example, but in any case, the code does what I need.

Comment: Ah, that is converting sign (MSB) magnitude (LSBs) into Twos Complement.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution -> In sequential circuits, the output must be in the form of a reg.
and  Next we need to know that in two's complement we start from bit zero to get to the end so the condition is incorrect.
If the zero bit is one, then the zero bit is unchanged and the rest of the bits change to not.

```
module ca2 (input  [2:0] a_i,output reg [2:0] f_o);
  always @(a_i[2:0] or f_o[2:0]) begin
    if (a_i[0] == 1'b1) begin
      f_o[0] = a_i[0];
      f_o[2:1] = (~a_i[2:1]);
    end
    else
    if(a_i[1]==1'b1) begin
      f_o[1:0] = a_i[1:0];
      f_o[2] = (~a_i[2]);
    end
    else
    if(a_i[2] == 1'b1) begin
      f_o = a_i ;
     end
  end
endmodule
```

The second solution -> In binary numbers, if we subtract the number from zero, we get two's complement .

```
module ca2 (input [2:0] a_i,output reg [2:0] f_o);
  always @(a_i[2:0] or f_o[2:0]) begin
    f_o = 3'b000 - a_i ;
  end
endmodule
```

The third solution -> all bits change to not and Finally, they are added to the number one (3'b000 = 3'b0)

```
module ca2 (input [2:0] a_i,output reg [2:0] f_o);
  reg [2:0] finish ;
  always @(a_i[2:0] or f_o[2:0]) begin
    finish = (~a_i);
    f_o = finish + 3'b001 ;
  end
endmodule
```